# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How should I extract "£70,004" text in dd, omitting "Investment sought" text which in dt.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url="https://www.seedrs.com/tanorganic"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "html.parser")

target = soup.find("dl", class_="investment_sought").text

print target

figure = soup.find("dd", class_="investment_sought").text

print figure
```

result :

```
Investment

sought:

£70,004

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 12, in <module>
    figure = soup.find("dd", class_="investment_sought").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to change the last 4 lines like below since there isn't a `dd` tag with `investment_sought` as class attrib value. Remove the first `print` stmt if you don't want..

```
target = soup.find("dl", class_="investment_sought")
print target.text
figure = target.find("dd").text
print figure
```

*Example:*

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import urllib2
>>> url="https://www.seedrs.com/tanorganic"
>>> page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "html.parser")
>>> target = soup.find("dl", class_="investment_sought")
>>> print target.text


Investment

sought:

£70,004

>>> figure = target.find("dd").text
>>> print figure
£70,004
>>>
```

Comment: Note that you can just pass `page` to `BeautifulSoup` - it works with file-like objects too.

Answer (score -2):

try:

## this will return text

figure = soup.find("dd", class_="investment_sought").text
except AttributeError:

## This will return None

figure = soup.find("dd", class_="investment_sought")

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and fix the indentation. The easiest way to post code is to paste it, then select it and click the "code block" button.