# extract tags from a large XML to csv

Tags: python, xml, csv, data-science, large-files

I need to open a large XML dataset with Excel (the file is the *concatenated LEI file* [here](https://www.gleif.org/en/lei-data/gleif-concatenated-file/download-the-concatenated-file).
The observations do not surpass the Excel workbook limit.
I tried extracting four columns from the XML to the csv. My code is:

```
cols = ["StartNodeID", "EndNodeID", "RelationshipType", "RelationshipDate_EndDate"]
rows = [] 

xmlparse = Xet.parse('D:\Descargas\concatenated_lei2file_StartNodeID.xml')
root = xmlparse.getroot()

Relationships = tree.findall('./RelationshipRecord/Relationship')

for elem in Relationships:
   StartNodeID = elem.find("./RelationshipRecord/Relationship/EndNode/EndNodeID").text
   EndNodeID = elem.find("EndNodeID").text
   RelationshipType = elem.find("RelationshipType").text
   RelationshipDate_EndDate = elem.find("RelationshipDate_EndDate").text

rows.append({"StartNodeID": StartNodeID,
             "EndNodeID": EndNodeID,
             "RelationshipType": RelationshipType,
             "RelationshipDate_EndDate": RelationshipDate_EndDate})

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)

df.to_csv('D:\Descargas\concatenated_lei2file_output.csv')
```

I get this error:

```
----> 4     StartNodeID = elem.find("./RelationshipRecord/Relationship/EndNode/EndNodeID").text
  5     EndNodeID = elem.find("EndNodeID").text
  6     RelationshipType = elem.find("RelationshipType").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

It is quite a large set. I was able to see the tree structure with firstobjectXML Editor.

[tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhxly.png)

I have tried:

- Simplifyng the tree structure with sublime text to start at the "Relationship" level.
- Deleting all columns but the StartNode.NodeID and the EndNode.NodeID

but keep getting the same error notice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434300/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-text)

Comment: Upload `concatenated_lei2file_StartNodeID.xml` (or a subset of it). Make sure it is a **VALID** xml doc. Explain how should the final csv look like.